# Configuring endpoint using wsHttpBinding using TransportWithMessageCredentials using protocol HTTP

Tags: web-services, wcf, wshttpbinding, transport-security

I have a legacy WCF service with 2 endpoints. One endpoint is configured using basicHttpBinding and it works fine.  I would like to configure the other endpoint to use wsHttpBinding and set the security mode to TransportWithMessageCredentials so that I can read the user name using:

```
string UserName = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
```

The protocol has to be HTTP and not use the secure HTTPS.
I found an answer similar to this problem and tried implementing it.  This is the web.config file:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="myBindingConfiguration1" closeTimeout="00:01:00">
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="SecureServiceEndpoint"  closeTimeout="00:01:00">
        <security mode="None">
        </security> 
      </binding>  
    </wsHttpBinding>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="HttpWithAuthentication">
        <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" allowInsecureTransport="true" />
        <context />
        <!-- needed for durable worklfows -->
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12Addressing10" />
        <httpTransport />
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Service.Service">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="insecure" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBindingConfiguration1"
          name="InsecureService" contract="Service.IService" />
        <endpoint address="secure" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="HttpWithAuthentication"
          name="SecureService" contract="Service.ISecureService" />
      </service>
    </services>
```

When I try to update the service reference, I get the error:
   messageVersion="Soap12Addressing10" is not a valid instance of type.

According to the MS documentation, this is a valid type. 
What message version should this attribute be?

I tried removing this attribute and the service reference can be updated but when accessing the secure endpoint, the client application throws an exception:
   "The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.\r\nParameter name: via".

I have read in the documentation that this approach is not recommended but this is a legacy application and I would like to see if it is possible.  If you can tell me why this is not recommended, I will be sure to explain it to my superiors.

**UPDATE:**

I got the configuration to populate the value,

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name
```

I created the binding below in the web.config file:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="PaymentSecureServiceEndpoint"  closeTimeout="00:01:00">
  <security mode="Message">
  </security> 
  </binding>  
</wsHttpBinding>
```

However, I was expecting the value to be the NAME of the client application and it is my username.  Again, the documentation that I have read indicated that this value would be the name of the client application accessing the web service. I tried setting the value of

```
 webSeviceName.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Test Client"
```

to the value of the application's name but that did not work either.

How can I get the name of the application that is accessing the web service?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't a customBinding require a base binding type that you customize? I use customBinding, but I use basichttpbinding as a starting point then add the components I want. I don't see that with yours.

Comment: The example of a custom binding did not mention that and the template is as I implemented. How do you attach a base binding to the custom binding?

Comment: I set up my binding in code, not in the config file. My code looks like this:         Dim binding As New System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding()
        Dim tmebe = New System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion.Soap11, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
        With tmebe.ReaderQuotas
          .MaxArrayLength = Integer.MaxValue
          .MaxBytesPerRead = Integer.MaxValue
          .MaxDepth = Integer.MaxValue
          .MaxNameTableCharCount = Integer.MaxValue
          .MaxStringContentLength = Integer.MaxValue
        End With

Comment: Plus:        
tmebe.MaxReadPoolSize = Integer.MaxValue
tmebe.MaxWritePoolSize = Integer.MaxValue
binding.Elements.Add(tmebe)

Comment: I added a wsHttpBinding to the config file and got a value in PrimaryIdentity.Name.  But it was my user name and I need the value of the client application.  As I wrote above, I would like to send the client application name to the web service.  How do I do that?

Comment: Sendinng the client app name to the host isn't really what you want to do. You define everything on the host side first, then the client calls those methods. For instance you can create three functions on the host: Ping(), Login(sLoginName, sPassword) and DoMyWork(sParam1, sParam2, sParam3), all with interfaces defined on the host. The clients would then call those using something like: http: //servername:8000/ServiceHost/Ping  ... You should be able to find plenty of sample code on the MS site or CodeProject to help out with this stuff.